# How to make variables with a function javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, automation, var

I've been in to automated tasks for a while but want to allow a user to create their own variable is their any way to this like `a = myname an = GUY (a) = an`
it would be quite useful please don't use a dictionary. Just exactly the same as a normal variable!

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have dynamic variable names, except in the case of global variables. You can fake it with `eval()`, but there are almost always better ways, like using object properties instead of variables *(which is why global variables can be dynamic, since they can be accessed as properties of `window`)*.

Comment: Please explain what problem you're really trying to solve because dynamically creating global variables is rarely ever the right solution.  If we can understand what your actual problem is, then we can better offer a good solution.  FYI, in describing an issue with a solution you are pursuing rather than the actual problem, you are falling into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which will pretty much never get you the best answer to a question.

Comment: See my answer below, this will create a normal variable which can be accessed in the normal way by other code I.e. obj.var1

Comment: I have used this function on [this](http://www.zombrom.com/experiments/varsetter.html) I used the function instead of the code inside for simpler user references

Comment: Cool, if you happy can you upvote my answer

Comment: My rank isn't high enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function setVariable(varName, value){
  this[varName] = value;
}
```

This will create a variable with the value and name on the window object or on the object the function is attached to (calling context).

Remember objects are just hash tables, you can get/set their variables like this

```
obj["var1"] = 123;
var var1 = obj["var1"];
```

So it's up to you but you can get set using a string name of the object member name.

Comment: Beware that `this` can be re-bound by other variable through `.bind()` or `.call()` or `.apply()` too.

Comment: Yes of course, the calling context is important, but this will achieve the need to set a variable at runtime using input from users.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks quite a bit of context, but in javascript terms, the first thing that comes to mind is a dictionary:

```
// userdictionary = { user => {} }
set_variable(user, variable, value){
    userdictionary[user][variable] = value;
}

get_variable(user,variable){
    return userdictionary[user][variable];
}
```

Comment: I did show in the example that I wouldn't use a dictionary!

Comment: You made that change somewhere in the middle of my writing this... Sorry. Why not use a dicctionary?

Comment: I want users to create variables not change dictionaries.

Comment: Try my answer it will create variables, without using dictionaries

Comment: Also I did mean the edit I meant a = myname an = GUY (a) = an

Comment: Not quite clear, but by edit you mean change after setting, yes you can do that with the second example in my answer

Comment: I mean't as easy to use as a variable and quite similar.